# Yii2: How to get an array object using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, yii2

I am using Yii2 framework for almost a year and now it's the first time I have to use Ajax with an array. I have a this Ajax request:

```
$.post("/laboratorio/analitos-grupos/analitos-grupos", json)
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log("Data Loaded: " + data);
        console.log("First object: " + data[0]);       
    });
```

But the console shows:

```
Data Loaded: [{"id":6,"color":"Blue"},{"id":4,"color":"Brown"},{"id":12,"color":"Red"}]
First object: [
```

I think it should shows:

```
Data Loaded: [{"id":6,"color":"Blue"},{"id":4,"color":"Brown"},{"id":12,"color":"Red"}]
First object: {"id":6,"color":"Blue"}
```

How can I get the first object?
Is jQuery the best way to use Ajax in Yii2?
I can't find a complete example on Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting a JSON String instead of an array of objects. You could specify that jQuery convert it by specifying `json` in the 4th argument in [`jQuery.post()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) :

```
$.post("/laboratorio/analitos-grupos/analitos-grupos", json, null, "json")
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log("Data Loaded: ", data);
        console.log("First object: ", data[0]);       
    });
```

Or, with the callback as success function :

```
$.post("/laboratorio/analitos-grupos/analitos-grupos", json, function(data) {
    console.log("Data Loaded: ", data);
    console.log("First object: ", data[0]);       
}), "json");
```

Comment: Since the callback is optional, the null isn't needed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the incoming JSON `string` to a JavaScript Object.

```
$.post("/laboratorio/analitos-grupos/analitos-grupos", json)
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log("Data Loaded: ", JSON.parse(data));
        console.log("First object: " + JSON.parse(data)[0]);       
    });
```